# Add HTML5 sandbox attribute to an iframe using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, sandbox

I've got an empty iframe and a button:

`<input type="button" name="B1" value="google"
onclick="frames['IFrameName1'].location.href='https://www.google.com/'">`

But (besides .location.href) i need to set the attribute `sandbox="allow-forms allow-scripts    allow-same-origin`, because the framed site "deframes". How to set location AND sandbox?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to do two things on one click event. Have a function do both of those things and fire that function on click.

```
window.onload = function(){
    var button = document.getElementsByName("B1")[0]
    var iframe = document.getElementsByName("IFrameName1")[0]
    button.addEventListener('click',addSandboxAndChangeLocation,false);

    function addSandboxAndChangeLocation(){
       frames['IFrameName1'].location.href='https://www.google.com/';
       iframe.sandbox = 'allow-forms allow-scripts allow-same-origin';
    }
}
```

Check it out on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/adamzr/73j5m/)!

Comment: Thanks, i am trying.. May be it'd be easier with jQuery?

Comment: It would be easier with jQuery for sure.

Comment: i'm afraid sandbox did not apply and it goes on deframing, while pure HTML iframe does not.

Comment: I think I see our problem. We have to set the sandbox attribute on the iframe dom element not the frame itself.

Comment: Sure, i see it is working on jsFiddle. Thank you for your help and time ;)

Comment: If it works on jsFiddle and does not work in browser, go to http://jsfiddle.net/draft/ and see the working code. May be this tip would help someone, as it helped me =)

Comment: Vote Up requires 15 reputation, unfortunnately. I've got 11

Comment: Great. i did it. The only thing you, could do now, Adam, is to correct your anwser, placing it in  "window.onload=function(){`your_anwser`}". That's why it worked in jsFiddle and did not in browser.

Comment: There's a good reason why the fiddle uses bing and wikipedia and not google. Trying to use google results in this:
Refused to display 'https://www.google.com/' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'.
Any idea how to circumvent the effect of such header?

Comment: It can't be circumvented. It is a security feature. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9158024/iframe-with-external-page-not-working#9158079

Comment: I try this on chrome the new value of the sandbox attr didn't apply anything.

Answer (score 9):

While you can set the `iframe.sandbox` property as a string, it's technically a [DOMTokenList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMTokenList) interface, so you can also `add()` and `remove()` single tokens:

```
let myIframe = document.createElement('iframe');
myIframe.sandbox.add('allow-scripts');
myIframe.sandbox.toggle('allow-forms');

console.log(myIframe.sandbox.toString())
// Returns: "allow-scripts allow-forms"

console.log(myIframe.outerHTML)
// Returns: <iframe sandbox="allow-scripts allow-forms"></iframe>
```