# TypeScript : IFrame sandbox property undefined, DOMSettableTokenList has no constructor

Tags: javascript, iframe, typescript, sandbox

I am creating an iFrame element in type script:

```
var iFrameElement : HTMLIFrameElement = document.createElement("iframe");
iFrameElement.sandbox.add('allow-forms');
iFrameElement.sandbox.add('allow-scripts'); 
iFrameElement.sandbox.add('allow-same-origin');
```

However, the sandbox property is undefined, so the add(value: string) here fails.

I cannot figure out how to instantiate the sandbox property either, here's the interface as defined in lib.d.ts:

```
interface HTMLIFrameElement {
    sandbox: DOMSettableTokenList;
}
interface DOMSettableTokenList extends DOMTokenList {
    value: string;
}
interface DOMTokenList {
    length: number;
    contains(token: string): boolean;
    remove(token: string): void;
    toggle(token: string): boolean;
    add(token: string): void;
    item(index: number): string;
    [index: number]: string;
    toString(): string;
}
```

I am thinking there is just some syntax I don't know how to use here, or there is some other trick to get this working. I searched extensively on this site and the internet at large, however results were not particularly helpful.

The answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13021500/add-html5-sandbox-attribute-to-an-iframe-using-javascript) unfortunately does not work in TypeScript (Type 'String' is missing property 'value' from type 'DOMSettableTokenList') which makes me want to cast some object to that type. I see [this guy](http://codepen.io/csuwldcat/pen/xqunC) appears to have re-implemented the type, but this seems too hacky to me right now.

Help me stackoverflow, you're my only hope.

Comment: Turns out that in FireFox and IE11, `sandbox` is a `DOMSettableTokenList` and the code that you posted should work (`sandbox` has an `add()` method). But in Chrome (which is probably what you're using), `sandbox` is a string. The interface declaration doesn't take this into account.

Comment: you might want to try changing the interface to `sandbox: any;` if this property varies depending on the browser

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally, if you are figuring out some browser specific implementations, I'd suggest you to cast (change type) to `any`, so you can write even:

```
(<any>iFrameElement).foo = "";
```

... but make some catching in your code.

This will allow you to use this for IE:

```
iFrameElement.sandbox.add('allow-forms');
iFrameElement.sandbox.add('allow-scripts');
```

And this for Chrome:

```
(<any>iFrameElement).sandbox = "allow-forms allow-scripts";
```