# Can we Invoke sandbox through css/jquery in iframe

Tags: jquery, css, html

I want to block pop-ups coming from iframe. I'm using php codeigniter where i'm taking iframes from db, 
**Note:** Iframes are dynamic we are just displaying it 
and thing i want to do is invoke **sandbox** in iframe tag,

```
<iframe src="demo_iframe_sandbox.htm" sandbox></iframe>
```

as user haven't done it in iframe is there a way that it could be done through css/jquery ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add HTML5 sandbox attribute to an iframe using Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13021500/add-html5-sandbox-attribute-to-an-iframe-using-javascript)

Comment: not really, my iframes are dynamic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### UPDATE

Actually this isn't really concating string I think, but it works here and it's dynamic.

[image]

#### SNIPPET 2

```js
var ifrm1 = $('<iframe id="ifrm1" name="ifrm1" src="about:blank" sandbox="allow-popups"></iframe>');

$('body').append(ifrm1);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

It works because it was blocked :P If you want to block popups the last thing you want to do is use a [sandboxed iframe](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_iframe_sandbox.asp). But if you want to set the sandbox attribute programmatically, you can use this by assigning the value by the array `allow[]`s index. Ex. `allow[2]` = `'allow-popups'`

#### SNIPPET 1

```js
var ifrm = document.querySelector('iframe');

var allow = ['allow-forms', 'allow-pointer-lock', 'allow-popups', 'allow-same-origin', 'allow-scripts', 'allow-top-navigation'];

ifrm.setAttribute('sandbox', allow[2]);
```

```html
<iframe src="demo_iframe_sandbox.htm" sandbox></iframe>
```

Comment: Its working in snippet, but when iframe is coming dynamically it won't work.

Comment: You can try concating strings. I'll add to the answer.