# How to embed external page using usercontrols to dashboard umbraco

Tags: c#, umbraco

I am new to Umbraco.

Is there any ways to embed a webpage (external for example: www.google.com.sg) in Umbraco admin page where I have created an custom section under site admin page using usercontrol (.ascx)?

I have tried using iFrame tag in usercontrol, the frame does appear but the content is not loaded.

I am currently using the latest version of Umbraco.

Comment: Can you post the source code your using?

Answer (score 0):

Try using a url to a site besides google. Google doesn't allow itself to be embedded in an iframe. See [iframe with external page not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9158024/iframe-with-external-page-not-working) for details.