# iframe does not work

Tags: html, iframe

The following code in a PHP script used to work. But now it does not work any more. I tried with the URL directly and it works well. I replaced the URL with something else it works too. I could not figure out what could go wrong. Any ideas? thanks.

```
<div id="fragment-7">
    <iframe src="http://www.pathwaycommons.org/pc/webservice.do?version=3.0&q=TP53&format=html&cmd=get_by_keyword&snapshot_id=GLOBAL_FILTER_SETTINGS&record_type=PATHWAY"
            WIDTH="100%"
            HEIGHT="600"
            MARGINWIDTH=0
            MARGINHEIGHT=0
            FRAMEBORDER="NO"
            SCROLLING="AUTO">
    </iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: Define *"does not work"*.

Comment: How is this a PHP issue, it could be a Chrome issue as Chrome is very strict on showing `ifame`s.

Comment: You need to learn to debug your code.

Comment: if your page is on a https connection, some browsers won't allow loading iframes from an HTTP connection.

Comment: does not show the page from pathwaycommon?

Comment: Sorry, first time here. I tried to add more code, but somehow I removed it and do not know how to add it back.

Comment: Tunaki fixed the problem for you.

Comment: @BIOROB Does Chrome show any errors in the Developer Console (press F12) when reloading the page?

Comment: Refuse to display because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'. You guys are awesome. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It might works fine. the problem is your url. please check it in source. I don't know exactly why. but the following below code works similarly

```
<iframe src="http://www.php.com/" width="200" height="200" marginheight="0"
                    frameborder="no"
                    scrolling="auto"></iframe>
```

Comment: Yes, I replaced the url with something else it works. however if I copy and past the url in my code in chrome directly it gets to the page with no problem at all, but not inside the iframe.

Comment: The reason may be like this (plz check it):- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9158024/iframe-with-external-page-not-working

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing wrong with your code, the page simply refuses to be framed by other domains.

The page returns the following HTTP header in the response headers.

```
X-FRAME-OPTIONS: SAMEORIGIN
```

The [`X-Frame-Options`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/X-Frame-Options) is a security feature by which a website can refuse framing. Since it is a security feature, there is no direct workaround unless you control the server you want to frame. The only thing you could do would be to proxy the request through a local PHP script or something similar.

Comment: Actually there is another iframe in the same script with a different url pointing to ucsc genome browser. It works fine. It looks like not all framing of external pages are refused. Anyone knows the criteria? thanks.

Comment: @BIOROB It depends on if the page sends the header above or not.