# Search Bar and Web page retrieval in R shiny box

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, shinyjs

Please check the snapshot below. I want to enter the url of any website in the search bar in the left box and the webpage can be displayed real time in the right box. The command "searchInput" I used is a shinyWidget and does not fulfill this. Please help me with a fix here. Also I would like to give a default web page link when the app runs like any site name. Please help me here.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinyWidgets)
ui <- dashboardPage(
dashboardHeader(title = "Web Page"),
dashboardSidebar(
width = 0
),
dashboardBody(
box(title = "Web Page Search", status = "primary",height = "155" 
,solidHeader = T,
    uiOutput("search_plot")),
box( title = "Web Page", status = "primary", height = "618",solidHeader = T, 
     uiOutput("wep_page"))))
server <- function(input, output) 
{ 
output$search_plot <- renderUI({
searchInput(inputId = "Id009", 
          label = "Enter the address", 
          placeholder = "A placeholder", 
          btnSearch = icon("search"), 
          btnReset = icon("remove"), 
          width = "100%")
})
output$wep_page <- renderUI({
})
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 3):

You could do something like this:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinyWidgets)
ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "Web Page"),
  dashboardSidebar(
    width = 0
  ),
  dashboardBody(
    box(title = "Web Page Search", status = "primary",height = "155" 
        ,solidHeader = T,
        uiOutput("search_plot")),
    box( title = "Web Page", status = "primary", height = "860px",solidHeader = T, 
         uiOutput("wep_page"))))
server <- function(input, output) 
{ 
  output$search_plot <- renderUI({
    searchInput(inputId = "Id009", 
                label = "Enter the address",
                btnSearch = icon("search"), 
                btnReset = icon("remove"), 
                value='https://',
                width = "100%")
  })
  output$wep_page <- renderUI({
    print(input$Id009)
    tags$iframe(src=input$Id009,width='100%',height='800px')
  })
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

Note that this may require some tweaking. i.e. check that the URL starts with `http://` or `https://` and probably some error handling, but this may help you in the right direction. Also, not all websites can be rendered in an iframe, for more info see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9158024/iframe-with-external-page-not-working).

Comment: Thanks boss for replying, however I am not able to see web content in the right box. I tried google.com but it is not appearing, kindly help me.

Comment: Hi @Adam, I tried both `https://google.com` and `https://nos.nl`. The first one does not work, the second one does. See the top answer of the [link I posted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9158024/iframe-with-external-page-not-working).

Comment: sure, however if there is an issue with frame, can't we do it with simple tags$html?

Comment: Sorry, I wish I could help you with that, but as far as I know: No.

Comment: I need one little clarity here as I being new in the domain, from a lehman's perspective, do you mean to say that R shiny cannot open all the websites, right?

Comment: Yes indeed. As far as I know, any website that has a X-FRAME-OPTIONS HTTP header cannot be opened in Shiny.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163306/discussion-between-adam-shaw-and-florian).